# Using Dict.update with nested update functions in Elm

Tags: function, dictionary, elm

I'm writing an Elm app where a major part of the state is in a `Dict` with `Record`s as values. I have an update function for the main state model, and an update function for the individual records in the `Dict`. Is there a way to use `Dict.update` with the record state update function?

The issue I'm having is that the state update function for the records returns what update functions usually return: a tuple with the updated object and any commands to trigger (e.g. `(newRecord, Cmd.none)`). But the `Dict.update` function needs to take in a record and return a record (e.g. just `newRecord`), not a tuple with a record and a command object.

Is there a way around this? Right now I've got it working using a combination of `Dict.get` and `Dict.insert`, but this seems clumsy.

Comment: With the varying answers already provided, could you clarify your question: Do you already have a child update that already produces a (model, Cmd Msg), and you want to know how to deal with it in the parent? Or do you want to create a new child update function that produces a (model, Cmd msg)? If you could share some code that would help too..

Comment: I already have a child updater and wanted to know how to deal with it in the parent. It looks like @halfzebra's solution is probably the simplest way, but every answer has been relevant. Almost wish I could correct-solution more than one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If update function for record always return `Cmd.none`, you can simplify it and return only the updated model.

Child modules do not have to follow `( Model, Cmd Msg )` convention if your application architecture does not require that.

If you do need to pass Commands from the lower level, it is also possible to re-structure your child module's `update` function to simplify those updates.

#### Example based on [example/http](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/blob/1d6a46cb0b15dc62499166131fc1b9b956ec3f21/examples/05-http.elm)

Here is an example of how you can split the update so that you could re-use the same logic in the top-level `update` without additional trickery.

```elm
update : Msg -> Model -> (Model, Cmd Msg)
update msg model =
  (updateModel msg model, updateCmd msg model)


updateCmd: Msg -> Model -> Cmd Msg
updateCmd msg model =
  case msg of
    MorePlease ->
      getRandomGif model.topic

    _ ->
      Cmd.none


updateModel: Msg -> Model -> Model
updateModel msg model =
  case msg of
    NewGif (Ok newUrl) ->
      Model model.topic newUrl

    _ ->
      model
```

If you need the updated model in `updateCmd`, then just pass it instead of current model or even pass both if you desire.

As a bonus, you can entirely omit unused branches of the case expression.

#### Using `Dict.update`

It will also be possible to use `updateModel` in `Dict.update` without retrieving the record and writing it back.

```
Dict.update childKey (Maybe.map (updateModel childMsg)) model
```

Comment: I *completely* forgot about the underscore syntax! Need to remember that I can use that, that definitely simplifies this a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you have a nested `Dict` structure in your model, like this:

```
type alias Model =
  { parentsAndChildren : Dict String (Dict String Int) }
```

Then it is not necessary to make the child `update` output a `Cmd`. Your update could look something like this:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model = 
  case msg of
    NewChild parentName childName age ->
      let
        newModel =
          { model
          | parentsAndChildren =
              model.parentsAndChildren
              |> Dict.update 
                   parentName 
                   (Maybe.map insertChild)
          }

      in
        (newModel, Cmd.none)

-- helper function to update a child Dict
insertChild: String -> Int -> Dict (String Int) -> Dict (String Int)
insertChild name age childDict =
  Dict.insert name age childDict
```

The only `update` function that **NEEDS** to output a `Cmd` is the update function in your top component.
So your child `update` function doesn't have to output a `Cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. I have this helper function in my one of my projects

```
updateDict : comparable -> msg -> Dict comparable b -> (msg -> b -> ( b, Cmd msg )) -> (comparable -> msg -> c) -> ( Dict comparable b, Cmd c )
updateDict uid act dict fn wrapper =
    case Dict.get uid dict |> Maybe.map (fn act) of
        Just ( m, e ) ->
            ( Dict.insert uid m dict
            , Cmd.map (wrapper uid) e
            )

        Nothing ->
            ( dict, Cmd.none )
```